# Trigger PostgreSQL to update one value based on the sum of three others

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am trying to make a boolean become true when the sum of three integers is equal to 100 and false when the sum is not equal to 100.

I am making a trigger function in Postgres to do that, but getting the following error:

> ERROR:  «db_fondos.checksize» is not a known variable
>   LINE 6:  DB_Fondos.CheckSize=true;

I hope you could help me.
Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_sum()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF DB_Fondos.SizeLarge+DB_Fondos.SizeMid+DB_Fondos.SizeSmall=100 then
    DB_Fondos.CheckSize=true;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I guess `DB_Fondos` is table name? If it true, in trigger function you should new `NEW.` instead

Comment: Yes DB_Fondos is a table name. Where should I put NEW. ?

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use a computed column for this instead of a trigger? The database manages the computation for you under the hood and you get an always up-to-date value when you query the table:

```
create table DB_Fondos (
    ...
    SizeLarge int,
    SizeMid int,
    SizeSmall int,
    check_sum boolean generated always as (
        coalesce(SizeLarge, 0) 
        + coalesce(SizeMid, 0) 
        + coalesce(SizeSmall, 0) = 100
    )
);
```

Comment: Nitpicking: COALESCE(col, 0) - columns could be nullable

Comment: The generated fields introduced since PostgreSQL 12. https://pgdash.io/blog/postgres-12-generated-columns.html  Before it trigger solution can be used

Comment: I have got a error when submiting the following code:
    "PeriodoInvAños" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 5,
    "PlazoFondoAños" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
    "MaxExtensionesGPAños" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
    "ExtensionesAprobMes" numeric NOT NULL,
    "SizeLarge" integer,
    "SizeMid" integer,
    "SizeSmall" integer,
    "CheckSize" boolean generated always as (coalesce(SizeLarge,0)+coalesce(SizeMid,0)+coalesce(SizeSmall,0)=100),
    CONSTRAINT "DB_Fondos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id_Fondo"),
    CONSTRAINT "Fondo" UNIQUE ("Fondo"),
    CONSTRAINT "Fondo2" UNIQUE ("Emisor")
);

Answer (score 1):

In a trigger, you relate to the newly inserted line with `NEW`, not with the table name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_sum()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.SizeLarge + NEW.SizeMid + NEW.SizeSmall = 100 THEN
        NEW.CheckSize = true;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```